# Updating EE versions and plugins

Tags: update

Just wondering how others out there track updates for their EE sites and plugins.

I come from the WordPress world where I had tools like [InifniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/) to see all my sites, if updates were available, etc.  I could then update as needed.  Typically pulling down to my dev server, testing the updates, and then pushing those to the live production site.

However now I am taking over a front-end dev team where we have 100+ EE sites.  They've always had a set it and forget it mentality and we are starting to change that.  Are their tools where I can monitor all my EE installs (not being on multi-site)?  What are best practices for when to update plugins and how can I easily be notified when they are available?  I'd like to start a maintenance schedule and a running list of what sites are using what plugins, so we can schedule times when we plan to test and push any necessary updates.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after [Lamplighter](https://lamplighter.io/) and the [add-on that accompanies it](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lamplighter).

Comment: In addition, you might consider [Updater](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/updater)

Comment: thanks to both of you for the quick replies.  Lamplighter is definitely what I'm looking for. Now a matter of convincing the bosses.

Comment: @low.  Since we don't want to update live sites without testing everything is ok.  Would it be reasonable to say that we might use Lamplighter to monitor our dev sites (we keep a dev site for each live site), then use Lamplighter to update our dev sites.  Then we'd push the dev sites to the live site using our standard deployment workflow?